# Javascript - Find all pairs of indexes in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Given an array such as

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c'],
```

am I able to find all pairs of indexes for a given "start" and "end" index.

Therefore, the above array would return the pairs [0, 2] and [5, 6] for the start character 'a' and the end character 'c'. There can be one to many pairs.

I know I can get the indexes of all 'a' and all 'c' in separate lists: a = [0, 5], c = [2,6] and then grab the first item of each list and so forth, but was curious if it was possible to get the indexes at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect indices in an array of objects and then map to your desired result.

```js
const chars = new Set(['a','c'])
const result = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c'].reduce((r, c, i) => {
  if(!chars.has(c)) return r;
  for(const set of r){
    if(!(c in set)){
      set[c] = i;
      return r;
    }
  }
  r.push({[c]:i});
  return r;
},[]).map(set => Object.values(set));

console.log(...result.map(JSON.stringify));
```